Does the Quran say that the Christians believe that Jesus is the literal offspring of god?
This has been on my mind for quite a while now
I’ve seen some people claim that the Quran says that Christians believe that Jesus is the literal son of god, those people then claim that they don’t believe that he’s the literal son of god, rather that that’s a title and not to be taken literally. This, in their head, means that the Quran is wrong about this
I’ve tried researching this but i don’t fully understand:
Does the Quran say that Christians believe that Jesus is the offspring of god?

The Quran, by definition, cannot be wrong. What can be wrong is the telling and our understanding.  What, exactly, are Christians? (Just to start with.) Not everyone living in "christian country" is Christian, not even by his own believing. To get it more complicated, there are many people that consider themself christens, but have different believes.

The Quran states that Christians believe Jesus is the son of God without specifying whether it is meant literally or not.


(V) Jews say: "Ezra was God's son," while Christians say: "Christ was
God's son." That is what they say with their mouths, imitating what
those have said who disbelieved before them. May God fight them off
for what they have trumped up! (9:30)

Reference
